# Accentuation and enums

Tags: html, mysql, forms, enums

If I have these options in a form:

```
<select id="abcd" name="xpto">
    <option value="Polícia Judiciária">Polícia Judiciária</option>
    <option value="Other value">Other value</option>
</select>
```

And a `enum('Other value','Polícia Judiciária')` in my mysql table.

The value `Polícia Judiciária` has accentuation, so my question is: Can have some problems using it as enum value? Or it is ok to mysql/form processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have UTF-8 codification on your database you shouldn't have any problem. So for example the following code: `INSERT INTO test (enum_col) VALUES ('policía');` works fine